# Change style for only clicked on view not all views

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` wrapped around an enclosing view, I want to change the colour of this enclosing view when it is clicked on i.e `onPressIn` , but the colour changes for all the views, I mean the mapped views, please how can I make the onPressIn change the style of only that particular view not all of them

```
const herbs = this.state.record.map(herb => (
  <TTouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPressIn={() => this.setState({ pressed: !this.state.pressed })}
    key={herb.id}
  >
    <View style={this.state.pressed ? BackStyles.herbBox : BackStyles.herb_box}>
      <Image
        style={BackStyles.image}
        source={{ uri: `${herb.name.replace(/ /g, "")}` }}
      />
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <Text style={BackStyles.header}>{herb.name}</Text>
        <Text style={BackStyles.sub}>{herb.bot}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TTouchableWithoutFeedback>
));

const BackStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  herb_box: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "95%",
    alignSelf: "center"
    //   height: '2%'
    //  justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  herbBox: {
    backgroundColor: "#28B564",
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "95%",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: when you do  `this.setState` it will re-render all

Comment: Any idea of how I can avoid using this.setstate?

Comment: you better use `Flatlist` for this purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to keep a track of boolean state of each `TTouchableWithoutFeedback` component created via `map`.

Instead of `pressed` being a boolean, make it into an object to keep a track of every component.

Something along the line of this.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    pressed: {}
  };

  handlePressedIn = i => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const pressed = { ...prevState.pressed };
      pressed[i] = !pressed[i];
      return { pressed };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const herbs = this.state.record.map((herb, i) => (
      <TTouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressIn={() => this.handlePressedIn(i)}
        key={herb.id}
      >
        <View
          index={i}
          style={
            this.state.pressed[i] === i && this.state.pressed
              ? BackStyles.herbBox
              : BackStyles.herb_box
          }
        >
          <Image
            style={BackStyles.image}
            source={{ uri: `${herb.name.replace(/ /g, "")}` }}
          />
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <Text style={BackStyles.header}>{herb.name}</Text>
            <Text style={BackStyles.sub}>{herb.bot}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TTouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ));
    return <div>{herbs}</div>;
  }
}
```

---

### Update

Here is a supplemental explanation as to explain how the code works.
Asked by [@Aravind S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516825/change-style-for-only-clicked-on-view-not-all-views/51517907?noredirect=1#comment90012713_51517907)

> could you please clarify my doubt in your answer? pressed is an object
>   pressed: {} and in handlePressedIn your doing pressed[i] =
>   !pressed[i]; where i is the index of the view...its an array
>   then...right? are you return an object array? so how is it working?

`pressed[i]` is initially `undefined` when a user clicks on the first time.
But `!undefined` returns true so initial value of `pressed[i]` will be true.

`pressed: {}` is initialized as an object to store only needed data.
If it was initialized as an array `pressed: []`, it'd waste space with `undefined` values.

Basically `return { clicked }` returns an object/dictionary with position (index) as a key.

[image]

## Working Demo

[image: Edit so.answer.51516825]

Comment: This is beautiful, Thanks @SungKim

Comment: The i variable though, in the this.state.pressed[i] where is it gotten from

Comment: Don't worry, I just replace i with `herb.id - 1`

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene `map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) automatically passes current index. `arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {...`

Comment: @SungKim could you please clarify my doubt in your answer? pressed is an object `pressed: {}` and in `handlePressedIn` your doing  `pressed[i] = !pressed[i];` where `i` is the index of the view...its an array then...right? are you return an object array? so how is it working? Thanks

Comment: @SungKim well said! Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I went a bit further to explain it in my blog https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/07/28/keep-track-of-on-off-states-of-reactjs-components/